# JavaScript 'click' not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a click event in a script associated with a div id - when i move the mouse in the div area and click (the mouse does not change cursor) it does not fire off the event listener
how do I make a div area clickable?

```
<script>
  var myEl = document.getElementById('dealdata');

  myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Hello world');
  }, false);
</script>



<td  BGCOLOR="#91be40" align="center" valign="center">
<div id="dealdata">
<br /><?echo $dpromo;?> 
<h1><?echo $dealvalue; ?></h1>
</div> 
</td>
```

Comment: yikes - shouldn't have stepped away my code does have dealdata - not sure how that got copied to the stack wrong - question was updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that `dealdata` hasn't yet been created when your script runs, because it is underneath the `<script>` element.

Use an `onload` handler:

```
 window.onload = function() {
     var myEl = document.getElementById('dealdata');

     myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('Hello world');
     }, false);
 };
```

As far as your mouse pointer not changing, it's not going to change unless you specifically tell it to. You can do this with CSS:

```
<style>
    #dealdata { cursor: pointer; }
</style>
```

Comment: yikes - shouldn't have stepped away my code does have dealdata - not sure how that got copied to the stack wrong

Comment: if you remove the items about #ddata - then this is the correct answer thank you! the issue was the <div> was after the script and therefore needed to be placed in the onload
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('dealdata'); //your div's id is 'ddata'
```

to

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('ddata');
```

JSFiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/lisp/Mr2jc/

Comment: yikes - shouldn't have stepped away
my code does have dealdata - not sure how that got copied to the stack wrong...

Comment: OK. Then you can either do what JLRishe suggested to wrap your script inside window.onload = funciont() {...};, or simply put <script> tag somewhere after that <div> tag. The problem in your current code is, when you call var myEl = document.getElementById('dealdata'); the <div> tag has not been created yet. Also see JSFiddle page in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your divs id is `ddata` but youre checking for `dealdata` in your javascript...

Comment: yikes - shouldn't have stepped away my code does have dealdata - not sure how that got copied to the stack wrong